# Returning Task.FromResult or just value in async code

Tags: c#, asynchronous

Consider this code:

```
class Program
{
    public async Task<int> ReturnTask(bool value)
    {
        if (!value)
        {
            return 3;
        }
        return await ReturnTaskImp();
    }

    public Task<int> ReturnTask2(bool value)
    {
        if (!value)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(3);
        }
        return ReturnTaskImp();
    }

    public async Task<int> ReturnTaskImp()
    {
        Task.Delay(3000); //do some really heavy work
        return 2; //return some value after heavy work done
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p = new Program();

        var t1 = p.ReturnTask(true).Result; //I know bad but not important now.
        var t2 = p.ReturnTask(false).Result;
    }
}
```

I've just finished reading [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456402.aspx)

and it seems that when you enter an async method the compiler has a statemachine that it tracks your current stack.

Now my question lies in which one will be better `ReturnTask` or `ReturnTask2`? Since `ReturnTask2` will not need a to create a new statemachine to just return a trivial value.

Should I be doing straight returns before entering into an async method or is `ReturnTask` sufficient and this may be an over optimization. I've actually looked at the IL code and it doesn't look like the compiler does any optimizations to avoid using this state machine.

Comment: If you are returning constant values, construct a static read-only (completed) Task instance instead of new tasks on each call.

Comment: I was just thinking that the costs too are in creating a completed task as well.

Comment: so, what is keeping you from constructing it as a lazy instance. `static readonly Lazy<Task<int>> _myInt3Task = new Lazy<Task<int>>(() => Task.FromResult(3));`

Comment: Async methods always comes with some cost. Don't give that cost unless you need it. `ReturnTask2` is better; stick with it.

Comment: @Alex nothing at all I just wanted clarification that ReturnTask2 is more justified, I'd expect the cache the constant task.

Comment: @Alex That's assuming that the method always computes the same value.  That isn't true in his (admittedly toy) example.  It's a useful pattern in some situations, but not all situations where you may or may not need to do asynchronous work involve computing a single value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both implementations are fine.  They certainly function identically.

Yes, you are avoiding the state machine by not marking the method as `async`.  If you're dealing with *extremely* performance sensitive code that could matter.  In most situations (that you're dealing with asynchrony at all) it's unlikely to matter.  After all, *any* `async` method could be re-written to avoid a state machine.  You're paying a small cost (the creating of one instance of a class per method invocation) in exchange for (potentially) making the method easier to write/read.  For *very* simple asynchronous methods `async` isn't actually helping make the method easier to read/write, in which case there's no need to pay the cost.  When you're actually leveraging the features of the state machine and making the method easier to write, it's almost always worth the (typically negligible) performance costs.

So if writing the non-async method is just as easy for you, go ahead and use that.  If you think the convenience of the `async` method is adding value for you, use that.